# Hook every variable reference and execute code

Tags: python

I have a Python app split across different files. One of them, models.py, contains, among PyQt5 table models, several maps referred from several PyQt5 form files:

```
# first lines:
agents_id_map = \
    {agent.name:agent.id for agent in db.session.query(db.Agent, db.Agent.id)}
# ....
# 2000 thousand lines
```

I want to keep this kind of maps centralized in a single point. I'm using SQLAlchemy also. Agent class is defined in a db.py file. I use these maps to fulfill the foreign key in another object, say, an invoice, like:

```
invoice = db.Invoice()
# Here is a reference
invoice.agent_id = models.agents_id_map[agent_combo.currentText()]
····
db.session.add(invoice) 
db.session.commit()
```

The problem is that the model.py module gets cached and several parts of the application access old data, and, if another running instance A of the app creates a new agent, and a running instance B wants to create a new invoice, the B running instance won't see the new Agent created by A unless restarts the app. This also happens if a user in the same running instance creates an agent and then he wants to create an invoice. My solutions are:

- Reload the module, to get the whole code executed again, but this could be very expensive.
- Isolate the code building those maps in another file, say maps.py, which would be less expensive to reload and change all code that references it through refactoring.

Is there a solution that would allow me to touch only the code building those maps and the rest of the application remains ignorant of the change, and every time the map is referenced from another module or even the same, the code gets executed, effectively re-building maps with fresh data?

Comment: Finally, I wrote a "refresh" method which is called every time the user navigates through one part of the application to another. This method only refreshes those necessary maps for that part of the application. I think it will be more elegant to be able to put a hook that gets executed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a solution that would allow me to touch only the code building those maps and the rest of the application remains ignorant of the change, and every time the map is referenced from another module or even the same, the code gets executed, effectively re-building maps with fresh data?

Certainly: put you maps inside a function, or even better, a class.

If I understand this problem correctly, you have stateful data (maps) which need regenerating under some condition (every time they are accessed?  Or just every time the db is updated?).  I would do something like this:

```py
class Mappings:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self._db = db
        ... # do any initial db stuff you need to here
    
    def id_map(self, thing):
        db_thing = getattr(self._db, thing.title)
        return {x.name:x.id for x in self._db.session.query(db_thing, db_thing.id)}

    def other_property_map(self, prop):
        ... # etc

mapping = Mapping(db)
mapping.id_map("agent")
```

This assumes that the mapping example you've given is your major use-case, but this model could easily be adapted for almost any other mapping you might want.

You would write a method of every kind of 'mapping' you need, and it would return the desired dictionary.  Note that here I've assumed you handle setting up the db elsewhere and pass a fully initialised db access object to the class, which is probably what you want to do---this class is just about encapsulating *mapper* state, not re-inventing your orm.

### Caching

I have not provided any caching.  But if you have complete control over the db, it is easy enough to run a hook *before* you do any db commits looking to see if you've touched any particular model, and then state that those need rebuilding.  Something like this:

```py
class DbAccess(Mappings):
    def __init__(self, db, models):
        super().init(db)
        self._cached_map = {model: {} for model in models}

    def db_update(model: str, params: dict):
        try:
            self._cached_map[model] = {} # wipe cache
        except KeyError:
            pass
        self._db.update_with_model(model, params) # dummy fn

    def id_map(self, thing: str):
        try:
            return self._cached_map[thing]["id"]
        except KeyError:
            self._cached_map[thing]["id"] = super().id_map(thing)
            return self._cached_map[thing]["id"]
```

I don't *really* think DbAccess should inherit from Mappings---put it all in one class, or have a `DB` class and a `Mappings` mixin and inherit from both.  I just didn't want to write everything out again.

I've not written any *real* db access routines, (hence my dummy fn) as I don't know how you're doing it (but clearly using an ORM).  But the basic idea is just to handle the caching yourself, by storing the mapping every time, but deleting all the stored mappings every time you do any commit transactions involving the model in question (thus rebuilding the cache as needed).

### Aside

Note that if you really do have 2,000 lines of manually declared mappings of the form `thing.name: thing.id` you really should generate them at runtime anyhow.  Declarative is all very well and good, but writing out 2,000 permutations of the same thing isn't declarative, it's just time-consuming---and doing the job a simple loop putting the data in ram could do for you at startup.

Comment: Mappings are at the beginning of a file with two thousand lines. Not that the entire file consists of mappings. The first part of the answer is useful for me.

Comment: @02435324 I'm relieved, the idea of you typing out 2,000 mappings is slightly terrifying....

Comment: I needed to associate some Combobox texts to their primary keys in the DB. Those PK are FK in other objects. These objects are built through forms. E.g, a form to create an invoice, a Combobox with names of agents, representing salespeople in the company. Then the invoice would have a field "agent_id" fulfilled with the value retrieved from that map. It is my first big database-driven application and I could not imagine other mechanics to build these relationships, which are spread through the whole application: lines, wh orders, payments, expenses, etc. Do you think that is correct?

Comment: @02435324 I don't have enough experience with the kind of application design you describe to be certain: it might be worth asking a dedicated question on software engineering.SE.  but fwiw I would build these mappings dynamically with some kind of class as described here.  Indexing by primary key sounds reasonable: just avoid exposing the key to the end user if you can: there's no need to make an attacker's life any easier.  Avoid relying on reloading a module: that's a pretty big code smell (imho)

Comment: The key is not exposed, in the source code, the keys are held by these mappings. The app will be used internally by maybe ten people. I don't know much about security but I think that the user would have to inspect the in-memory values of my data structures to reach the password and user of the DB, for example, and, from what I know, this would be done running the program inside a debugger. In the near future, I will develop a little web flask application for customers. There, security may be a concern. I could protect against sql inyection, for example.

Comment: I mean, if you read the source code, you won't find literals for passwords and users. Anyway, I don't plan to ship the source code. But may it could be decompiled or something and it is protected against that.